# Cannot query Firestore database on multiple values

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database full with cars. The `JSON` format is this:

```
docId: {
        "countries": ["Netherlands"]
        "cities": ["Amsterdam"]
   }
```

I cannot query both arrays.

```
db.collection("EU-CARS")
    .whereArrayContains("countries", "Netherlands")
    .whereArrayContains("cities", "Amsterdam");
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noticed, Firestore allow you to filter your cars using only one `whereArrayContains()` method call. If you will use more than one, an error like this will occur:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Query. Queries only support having a single array-contains filter.

There are two ways in which you can solve this. The first one would be to change the structure your car document like this:

```
docId
  |
  --- filters
       |
       --- "country": "Netherlands"
       |
       --- "city": "Amsterdam"
```

In this way you can filter your database using:

```
Query query = db.collection("EU-CARS").
    .whereEqualTo("filters.country", "Netherlands")
    .whereEqualTo("filters.city", "Amsterdam");
```

Chaining multiple `whereEqualTo()` methods is permitted in Firestore.

Or if you still want to use arrays, simply concatenate both names into a sigle one:

```
docId
  |
  --- "countries_cities": ["Netherlands_Amsterdam", "Netherlands_Utrecht"]
```

The corresponding query should look like this:

```
db.collection("EU-CARS")
    .whereArrayContains("countries_cities", "Netherlands_Amsterdam");
```

**Edit:**

If you have multiple countries/cities, then the structure of your document should look like this:

```
docId
  |
  --- filters
       |
       --- "Netherlands": true
       |
       --- "Amsterdam": true
       |
       --- "Utrecht": true
```

In this way you can filter your database using:

```
Query query = db.collection("EU-CARS").
    .whereEqualTo("filters.Netherlands", true)
    .whereEqualTo("filters.Amsterdam", true);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll go with the arrays but how about storing multiple cities and countries when using the first solution? Just curious.

Comment: Oh ya, you're right. My bad, sorry about that, Please see my updated answer.