# Firestore query a filed against multiple values

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to query documents fields against an array of values where it would return the fields which contain one of the array elements values

```
                 _fireStore
                .collection('articles')
                .orderBy('created')
                .where('projectName', isEqualTo: listHearted)
                .getDocuments()
                .asStream(),
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Please edit the question to show examples of what documents you might expect to receive from a query.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to perform a query that returns items that match one of a number of values in a certain field. The workaround is to perform a query for each hearted project, and merge the results on the client.

Also see:

- [How to perform compound queries with logical OR in Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632042/how-to-perform-compound-queries-with-logical-or-in-cloud-firestore/48832819)
- [Firebase Firestore - OR query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726673/firebase-firestore-or-query)
- [Firestore - query all documents which field matches values in a list (like SQL IN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57181581/firestore-query-all-documents-which-field-matches-values-in-a-list-like-sql-i)
- [Firebase Query Or'ing whereEqualTo for a list of possible values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332081/firebase-query-oring-whereequalto-for-a-list-of-possible-values)
- [Cannot query Firestore database on multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55686460/cannot-query-firestore-database-on-multiple-values)
- this [tracking issue on Github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/321)

Answer (score 1):

i've done it using a stream within a stream.

```
 Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> streamDoc;
  StreamController<List<DocumentSnapshot>> controller =
  StreamController<List<DocumentSnapshot>>();

 void docRef() {
Firestore _fireStore = Firestore.instance;

Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshot = _fireStore
    .collection('articles')
    .orderBy('created')
    .getDocuments()
    .asStream();

List<DocumentSnapshot> listDoc = List<DocumentSnapshot>();
snapshot.listen((snapshot) {
  snapshot.documents.forEach((e) {
    if (SharedPrefList.listHearted
            .contains(e.data['projectName'].toString()) &&
        widget.type == 'hearted') {
      listDoc.add(e);
      controller.add(listDoc);
    }
    if (SharedPrefList.listSeen
            .contains(e.data['projectName'].toString()) &&
        widget.type == 'seen') {
      listDoc.add(e);
      controller.add(listDoc);
    }
  });
});
```

}